# problem with php and regex

Tags: php, regex

i saw some things look a like but not the same, i hope you can assist:

i am trying to execute the first result from youtube search results by

parse youtube search result page and find this: (belong to the first video)

```
<img alt="Thumbnail" src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/kUJLn7645Zs/default.jpg">
```

then i want to get the video code which is this: (kUJLn7645Zs)

this is my code and something doesn't work, please assist

```
$res = file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=take+me");
preg_match_all('/<img\s[a-zA-Z0-9=\'\":\/.()_@&\s]*>/',$res,$matches);

$str = $matches[0][0];
$tempArray = array();
$tempArray = explode('/',$str);
echo $tempArray[count($tempArray) - 2];
```

Comment: Why are you using `preg_match_all()` if you only want the first result?

Comment: actually i want the first 5, that was jsut an example

Comment: if you can use zend, using [youtube api](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Searching_for_Videos) would be much lighter than loading a page

Answer (score 1):

Why not :

```
if(preg_match_all('/\<img [^\>]* src\="(https?:)?\/\/i[0-9]\.ytimg\.com\/vi\/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/default\.jpg" ?[^\>]*\>/',$res,$matches))
{
  $firstVid= $matches[2][0];
}
else
{
  $firstVid= "";
}

print_r($matches);
```

?

Comment: hey, that doesnt return a thing. did you check it?

Comment: so the regex doesnt fit. can you check again, because it doesnt help me :)

Comment: it was fitting with the <img /> you gave in the example, I've changed my answer so it fit also with what I get from youtube

Comment: i try this:

if(preg_match_all('/\<img [^\>]* src\="(https?:)?\/\/i[0-9]+\.ytimg\.com\/vi\/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/default\.jpg" ?\>/',$res,$matches))
{
  $firstVid= $matches[2][0];
  echo $firstVid;
}
else
{
  $firstVid= "";
}

still doesnt return

Comment: I tried from somewhere else and the code of image was `<img src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/Cvdk7vB3jM4/default.jpg" alt="Thumbnail" >` I've changed my post to match it too.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to use regex to parse html.

Try using a pre-made framework like [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather us

```
explode("/", "myvar");
```

And just take the part that interests me

Answer (score 0):

this is the complete answer.

thank you all and a big thank you to Enki :)

```
$res = file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=take+me");
if(preg_match_all('/\<img [^\>]* src\="(https?:)?\/\/i[0-9]\.ytimg\.com\/vi\/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/default\.jpg" ?[^\>]*\>/',$res,$matches))
{
  $firstVid= $matches[0][0];
}
else
{
  $firstVid= "";
}

$tempArray = array();
$tempArray = explode('/',$firstVid);
echo $tempArray[count($tempArray) - 2];
```